# Call function after another completes in a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a for loop where I am calling three functions. I need the functions to run in sequence only after the previous one has completed.

I have tried to achieve this using callbacks but it doesn't seem to be working.

Here's the code:

```
 for(let i=0;i<boxval.length;i++){
        var value=boxval[i];
        a(value,function(returnedValue){
            b(returnedValue,function(returnedValue){
                    c(returnedValue,function(returnedValue){
                        d();
                    });
             });
        });


    }



        function a(val, callback){
            $
            .ajax({
                type : "get",
                url : "myservlet",
                beforeSend : function() {
                    $(
                            '#text1')
                            .css(
                                    {
                                        "color" : "red"
                                    });
                    $(
                            '#text1')
                            .text(
                                    "Running Graph");
                },

                data : {
                    "boxval" : val
                },
                success : function(
                        responseText) {
                    $(
                            '#text1')
                            .css(
                                    {
                                        "color" : "green"
                                    });
                    $(
                            '#text1')
                            .text(
                                    responseText);


                    callback(val);

                }
});

        }
        function b(val, callback){
            $
            .ajax({
                type : "get",
                url : "ConnectServlet",
                beforeSend : function() {
                    $(
                            '#text2')
                            .css(
                                    {
                                        "color" : "red"
                                    });
                    $(
                            '#text2')
                            .text(
                                    "Copying Files and preparing pSet");
                },
                data : {
                    "boxval" : val
                },
                success : function(
                        responseText) {
                    $(
                            '#text2')
                            .css(
                                    {
                                        "color" : "green"
                                    });
                    $(
                            '#text2')
                            .text(
                                    responseText);


                    callback(val);

                }

        });

        }
        function c(val, callback){
            $
            .ajax({
                type : "get",
                url : "CopyServlet",
                beforeSend : function() {
                    $(
                    '#text3')
                    .css(
                            {
                                "color" : "red"
                            });
            $(
                    '#text3')
                    .text(
                            "Running Dynamic Diff Graph");
        },
        data : {
            "boxval" : val
        },  
        success : function(
                responseText) {
            $(
                    '#text3')
                    .css(
                            {
                                "color" : "green"
                            });
            $(
                    '#text3')
                    .text(
                            responseText);


            callback(val);


        }
        });
        }

        function d(){
            $(
            '#summary')
            .show();
}
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I get this to work?

Comment: Even if any of the solution does work for you, I still doubt the execution will be proper as you have indexes in the callbacks you may not point to the proper index at the time the callback is executing, The index might have jumped to next value..

Comment: Yup that does seem to be happening. I don't think using a variable will help either. Any idea what I can do?

Comment: Gave you my solution, see if that helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As many have given you solutions already I wont spare time giving the same solution, I still am sure that the execution will not happen as expected, Since you have callbacks which are assigned values using `Index` it will break for sure. Reason is when the ajax is success and the callback is executed the the index will be incremented to point to a different number. Now your callbacks will take these values which is wrong.

So the solution to handle this will be simply to **pass back the value passed into the ajax call back into the callback**

Change the code as below.

```
for (i = 0; i < boxval.length; i++) {
    a(boxval[i], function (returnedValue) {
        b(returnedValue, function (returnedValue) {
            c(returnedValue);
        });
    });
}
```

And change your `callback()` to `callback(val)` , `val` is what passed into the ajax function.

So the conclusion is to change the `for loop` and the `callback` as suggested above and move the `callback(val)` inside of the `success` of ajax.

**EDIT:** Since you want the functions to execute synchronously you can use **Recursive** function. That is execute the function from first index unless all the indexs are covered. Here is a sample **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vvtx66kb/2/)** (watch console output)

```
var boxval = [1, 2, 3]

function RecursiveExecution(index) {
  var value = boxval[index];  
  a(value, function(returnedValue) {    
    b(returnedValue, function(returnedValue) {      
      c(returnedValue);

      if (index < boxval.length -1) { // if there are more items do this process again
        RecurrsiveExecution(++index);  
      }
    });
  });
}

RecursiveExecution(0); // initiate the recursive function.
```

Comment: No unfortunately its not working. It works fine if there's just one iteration in the loop but more any more iterations, it runs through function a as many times as the number of iterations and only then shifts to function b. 
Check my edited question

Comment: @karansabhani you did not update the code as I have suggested . I still see `b(value..` it should be `b(returnedValue`

Comment: I tried that too. Still seems to be the same issue.

Comment: @karansabhani here is a test case https://jsfiddle.net/vvtx66kb/1/ Open up the console window and you can see the logs, Each function is executed with all the values from the array.. It will not be synchronous, as you are dealing with ajax which is asynchronous, But you can see that the values are being passed into all the functions correctly

Comment: Ok thanks. the functions seem to be getting the right values but the order is pretty messed up. There really is no way to get it to execute synchronously?

Comment: order will be messed up as its asynchronous operation, YES there is a way to execute it in a order. I will update my answer

Comment: @karansabhani you can check my updated answer. Idea is to replace forloop logic with recursive function.

Comment: Yup, this covers it completely. Thanks a ton.

Comment: @karansabhani glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

$.ajax are promises. You can do it like that:

```
function a(){
        return $.ajax();
    }
    function b(){
        return $.ajax();
```

and then

```
 a().then(b).then(c)
```

etc. It should works.

Answer (score 1):

All the functions has ajax call that is done asynchronously by definition.
Try wrapping the ajax calls with some promise mechanism that will allow you the call the callback function when the ajax call is done.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to accomplish what you are trying to do is using promise, but if you are not familiar with that(and by your question you are not) it's a bit hard to learn in a few minutes, but I recommend it.

For your code I would have try this:

```
    function a(val, callbackB, callbackC)
        {
                $.ajax({
                    type : "get",
                    url : "myservlet",
                    beforeSend : function() {
                      $('#text1').css({"color" : "red"});
                        $('#text1').text("Running Graph");
                    },
                    data : {"boxval" : val},
                    success : function(responseText) {
                        $('#text1').css({"color" : "green"});
                        $('#text1').text(responseText);
                        callbackB(val,callbackC)
                    }
          });
            }

    var cbB =   function b(val, callback)
            {
                $.ajax({
                    type : "get",
                    url : "ConnectServlet",
                    beforeSend : function() {
                        $('#text2').css({"color" : "red"});
                        $('#text2').text("Copying Files and preparing pSet");
                    },
                    data : {"boxval" : val},
                    success : function(responseText) {
                        $('#text2').css({"color" : "green"});
                        $('#text2').text(responseText);
                        callback(val);
                    }
           });
            }

    var cbC =function c(val){
                $.ajax({
                    type : "get",
                    url : "CopyServlet",
                    beforeSend : function() {
                        $('#text3').css({"color" : "red"});
                    $('#text3').text("Running Dynamic Diff Graph");},
                data : {"boxval" : val},    
                success : function(responseText) {
                    $('#text3').css({"color" : "green"});
                    $('#text3').text(responseText);
                }
              });
            }


 for(i = 0 ; i < boxval.length; i++){
       a(boxval[i],cbB,cbC)
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing this:

```
function blah() {
    success: function(responseText) {
        // ...
    }
    callback();
}
```

Put `callback();` inside `success` and it will work

```
function blah() {
    success: function(responseText) {
        // ...
        callback();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For that kind of things i would recommended to use [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

but if you don't want to dive in it, i would suggest that you call the next function after getting success.

```
function a() {
    success: function(responseText) {
        // code here..
        callback();
    }
}
function b() {
    success: function(responseText) {
        // code here..
        callback();
    }
}
function c() {
    success: function(responseText) {
        // code here..
        callback();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AJAX is asynchronous call, meaning that it will still be doing it's work and the rest of the javascript code will continue with the execution independantly of it.

So, you just have to put your callback in success callback of each ajax call. What it will do is call your callback function when ajax returns a success. For example:

```
function a(val, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "myservlet",
        beforeSend: function () {
            $('#text1').css({ "color": "red" });
            $('#text1').text("Running Graph");
        },
        data: {
            "boxval": val
        },
        success: function (responseText) {
            $('#text1').css({ "color": "green" });
            $('#text1').text(responseText);

            callback();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Still the issue is not resolved as the OP has a loop and uses index in the call back which will not point to actual index properly when the callbacks are executed, CLOSURES issue

Comment: Yeah, he just gotta assing that boxval[i] to a variable inside a loop and pass that variable instead of boxval[i] and it will then pass the correct value

Comment: I guess that will still have issue, when the callback is executed the variable might have a new value.. :p

Comment: No it won't, I had the same problem with arrays and indexes, and assinging it to a variable will work fine in a loop.

Comment: Sure? because this is asynchronous operations,

Comment: I know, just try it and see. :D told you, had the same problem, just put var some_variable = boxval[i]; inside the loop, not outside

Comment: Just tried it.. https://jsfiddle.net/vvtx66kb/ see the console output..

Comment: The variable "value" in your console.log will not be correct, but as you see, the x is the one that you have passed to the ajax call, and it is correct.

Comment: Thats what I meant, the value will be wrong, But you said it will be right. So thats the proof :)

Comment: We missunderstood. I got your point, but I was saying that if he passed a boxval[i] as a first parameter to a function that it might have given the wrong value, variable from a loop shouldnt be used like that directly in an anonymous function.

Comment: `Yeah, he just gotta assing that boxval[i] to a variable inside a loop and pass that variable instead of boxval[i] and it will then pass the correct value ` This point doesnt seem to mean what you say now :p